# react-native redux props changes back to undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to add a filter to my app, but for some reason selectedValue in the `<Picker>` component doesn't stick with the option I select. I can see the filter text changing from "all" to "lobby" in the top left, however as soon as the player list fully renders, it changes back to "all." and playerListFilterType prop is set to undefined. I stepped through the code in a debugger, and it stays "lobby" until the list re-renders. The action itself works, so the list is showing accurate results.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, Picker } from 'react-native'
import PlayerList from '../components/PlayerList'
import { fetchPlayerListAsync, filterPlayers } from '../redux/actions/player_actions';

import NavigationHeaderTitle from '../components/NavigationHeaderTitle'
import PlayerStatusFilterPicker from '../components/pickers/PlayerStatusFilterPicker'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class PlayerListScreen extends React.Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const playerStatusFilterPicker = (
      <PlayerStatusFilterPicker
        playerListFilterType={navigation.getParam('playerListFilterType')}
        filterPlayers={navigation.getParam('filterPlayers')}
        playerList={navigation.getParam('playerList')}
      />
    )

    return {
      headerTitle: navigation.getParam('headerButton'),
      headerRight: playerStatusFilterPicker
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchPlayersAsync();
  }

  setNavigationParams = () => {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      headerButton: this.headerButton,
      playerList: this.props.playerList,
      playerListFilterType: this.props.playerListFilterType,
      filterPlayers: this.props.filterPlayers
    })
  }

  // navigation header element
  headerButton = () => (
    <NavigationHeaderTitle
      handleDataRequest={this.fetchPlayersAsync}
      titleMessage={(this.props.fetchingData) ? 'fetching list of players' : `${this.props.playerList.length} online`}
    />
  )

  fetchPlayersAsync = async () => {
    await this.props.fetchPlayerListAsync();
    this.setNavigationParams()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <PlayerList
          playerList={this.props.playerList}
          fetchingData={this.props.fetchingData}
          handleDataRequest={this.fetchPlayersAsync}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    fetchingData: state.player.fetchingData,
    playerList: state.player.playerList,
    unfilteredPlayerList: state.player.unfilteredPlayerList,
    playerListFilterType: state.player.playerListFilterType
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPlayerListAsync, filterPlayers })(PlayerListScreen)
```

and here's what the filter component looks like, but I don't think the problem lies here:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { 
  View,
  Picker
} from "react-native";
import * as constants from '../../constants'

class PlayerStatusFilterPicker extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Picker 
          selectedValue={this.props.playerListFilterType}
          onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.props.filterPlayers(itemValue, this.props.playerList)}
          style={{ height: 40, width: 100 }}
        >
          <Picker.Item label='all' value='all' />
          <Picker.Item label="lobby" value={constants.IN_LOBBY} />
          <Picker.Item label="in game" value={constants.IN_GAME} />
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default PlayerStatusFilterPicker;
```

Here's what the reducer looks like:

```
    // show only the players that are waiting in the main lobby
case actionTypes.SHOW_PLAYERS_IN_LOBBY: {
  const filteredList = action.payload.filter(player => player.status === constants.IN_LOBBY)
  return { playerList: filteredList, playerListFilterType: constants.IN_LOBBY, fetchingData: false }
}

// show only the players that are currently playing
case actionTypes.SHOW_PLAYERS_IN_GAME: {
  const filteredList = action.payload.filter(player => player.status === constants.IN_GAME)
  return { playerList: filteredList, playerListFilterType: constants.IN_LOBBY, fetchingData: false }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can use navigation props, `navigation.state.param.playerListFilterType`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using componentDidUpdate lifecycle method. Like so:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if (this.props.playerListFilterType != prevProps.playerListFilterType) {
  this.props.navigation.setParams({
    playerListFilterType: this.props.playerListFilterType
  })
}
```

}